# Is it possible to put a modal inside a card?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that's inside a Bootstrap Card for a confirmation if the user really wants to cancel a booking. The problem is that it doesn't show up when clicked. I see the `fade` effect and that's about it.

```
<% if Date.current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == data.formatted_date_time_for_comparison %>
  <%= f.submit 'Cancel Booking', class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% else %>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Cancel Booking</button>
  <div class="modal fade text-dark" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm Cancellation</h3>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure you want to cancel this booking?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= f.submit 'Cancel Booking', class: "btn btn-danger" %>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It compares the current date to the date of the booking's departure date and it gives a submit button straight to the controller, which in turn rejects it because cancelling on the same date isn't allowed. If that's not the case it gives a button for a modal to activate.

I'm mostly sure it's because of it buried beneath divs, specifically divs with bootstrap card classes.

Here are its parent divs:

```
<div class="margin-top" style="width: 600px;">
  <div class="bg-dark p-3 rounded">
    <h3>Reservations</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="accordion" class="mt-3 mb-4">
    <div class="card bg-dark">
    <% @reservations.reverse().each do |data| %>
      <a class="btn text-light card-header" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#id-<%= data.id %>">
      <div class="row" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="col">
          <strong>Name: </strong><%= data.name %><br><br>
          <!-- other records -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <strong>Departure: </strong><%= data.departure %><br>
          <!-- other records -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div id="id-<%= data.id %>" class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <strong>Base Price: </strong><%= data.base_price %><br>
            <!-- other records -->
          </div>
          <div class="col d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end">
            <%= form_for @cancellation, url: del_rsrv_path do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: data.id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :datetime, value: data.formatted_date_time_for_comparison %>
            <!-- code posted above here -->
```

I checked and it does work just below the first div (didn't check on deeper divs), but the problem would be passing the form params there. I'm asking if there's a workaround in either situation.

EDIT: I renamed the `data-bs-target` name and its respective id name and it somehow works now.

Comment: Bootstrap modals are designed to open over everything else in the body. It doesn't matter if you put the modal code in the start, middle or end of the code. They will always open on top of all. You are better off creating something custom, or find another package for what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 5.1.0